# ASP.NET MVC invoking webservice through AjaxOptions.Url

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Say I wanted to invoke the following url that returns Json through an Ajax call:

http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=westminster+abbey"

How does on go about doing this?

I tried using the AjaxOptions.Url like this:

```
<span id="status">No Status</span>
<div>
     @Ajax.ActionLink("Test", null, null, 
              new AjaxOptions 
              {
                  UpdateTargetId = "status",
                  Url = "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=renderBasicSearchNarrative&q=westminster+abbey"
              })
</div>
```

but the url does not get invoked when i click on "Test" link.

I also tried:

```
    <div>
          <button value="get closest POI" onclick="testNominatim()"></button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function testNominatim() {
            alert("called");
            $.ajax(
                {
type: "GET",
                url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=onGetNominator&q=westminster+abbey",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }                });

 function onGetNominator(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    </script>
```

When I click on button, message box shows but webservice does not get invoked.

I am probably missing something trivial but what is it?

TIA.

**Edit 1**  Changes to reflect actual script.

Comment: You need to be using JSONP, not plain JSON since you're talking to a server in a different domain.  Change the `dataType` in your second example and add `&callback=?` to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for additional tip.  Included the changes but still missing something as call back is not being invoked.

Comment: You're using a POST, shouldn't you be using a GET?

Comment: @tvanfosson, I have since made some changes, including using a GET, since the original post. Still no go.  Is what am I doing theoretically correct?

Comment: I didn't notice they were using `json_callback` instead of `callback`.  That makes it a little different.  See my answer, including a link to a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the second form would be my proposed solution.  Note that the service requires a parameter named `json_callback` instead of the standard `callback` parameter for the callback function.  This requires a bit of extra set up in the AJAX call.

Try the following.  Note that I've changed the handler to apply it using code rather than in the markup.  That's a better practice.  I'm also using jQuery 1.7+.  JSFiddle can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/xVBBN/

```
<div>
    <button>get closest POI</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click',function() {
        alert('called');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&q=windsor+[castle]&addressdetails=1&limit=3&viewbox=-1.99%2C52.02%2C0.78%2C50.94&exclude_place_ids=41697',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'json_callback',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data[0].place_id);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much.  Was doing something silly by wrapping test button in an Html.BeginForm() causing it to not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="testNominatim()">get closest POI</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testNominatim() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=onGetNominator&q=westminster+abbey",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }

    function onGetNominator(msg) {
        alert(msg[0].place_id);
    }
</script>
```

Things to notice (compared to your original code):

- `dataType: "jsonp"`
- you don't need a success callback because the success callback is your `onGetNominator` function
- you don't need `contentType: 'applicatin/json'` because you are not sending a JSON request

or if you wanted to use an anonymous success callback:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="testNominatim()">get closest POI</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testNominatim() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?format=json&json_callback=?&q=westminster+abbey",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg[0].place_id);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Things to notice (compared to your original code):

- `json_callback=?` in the query string which will be replaced by jQuery with a random name allowing to invoke the anonymous success callback
- you no longer need the `onGetNominator` function because we use the anonymous success callback
- you don't need `contentType: 'applicatin/json'` because you are not sending a JSON request

And as far as the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper is concerned, I don't think that it support JSONP.